# form and div class on the same line

Tags: html, css, forms

I have an html form and a div class. Both are represented by buttons and are appearing in different lines. (one below another). I want both the buttons to appear on the same line. How can I achieve this?

```
  <div class="form">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'mytab' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="drilldown_filter" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="myFunction()" disabled><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
      <input type="hidden" id="data" name="input name" value="">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="button-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="javascript:history.go(-1);" disabled><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></button>
  </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this style for both divs:

```
<style>
    .form{
        display: inline-block
    }
    .button-group{
        display: inline-block
    }
</style>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

include Style = "float:left" for form  div.

```
<div class="form" style="float:left;">
<form method="POST" action="">

    <button type="submit" name="drilldown_filter" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="myFunction()" disabled><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down">sdfgsdfg</i></button>
  <input type="hidden" id="data" name="input name" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

```
.form,.button-group {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is make `div.both` that will contain both those divs and put a `display: flex` on that `div.both` in the CSS.

```
 <div class="both" >
 <div class="form">
    <form>
     <button>uno</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="button-group">
  <button>dos</button>
  </div>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
div.both {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste this code

```
<div class="form" style="float: left;">
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'mytab' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="drilldown_filter" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="myFunction()" disabled><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
  <input type="hidden" id="data" name="input name" value="">
</form>
```